# Find out access token sent as header using python-requests

Tags: python-3.x, curl, python-requests

When an API is called using curl, it returns response whereas when the same API is called using the `requests` library in python, it produces an error:

Curl call:

```
curl -X GET --header "Accept: application/json" --header "Authorization: oauth_code" "https://api.getgo.com/G2W/rest/organizers/5913931473742004748/historicalWebinars?fromTime=2017-07-13T10%3A00%3A00Z&toTime=2017-09-10T10%3A00%3A00Z"
```

Requests code:

```
import requests
import datetime
date_11_days_back = (datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=11)).isoformat()
date_now = datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()
webinars_url = "https://api.getgo.com/G2W/rest/organizers/5913931473742004748/historicalWebinars"
params = {
    'fromTime': date_11_days_back,
    'toTime': date_now
}
headers = {
    'Authorization': 'oauth_token'
}

last_week_webinars = requests.get(webinars_url, headers=headers, params=params)
```

This call result into error saying `b'{"errorCode":"InvalidRequest","description":"Your request could not be processed because one or more of the request parameters are an invalid type.","incident":"5308828452798993933"}'`

I know , this is something specific to the API.

Passing `headers` as follows also produces an error:

```
headers = {
        'Authorization': "TOK:{}".format(goto_webinar_access_token)
    }
```

Error: `b'{"int_err_code":"InvalidToken","msg":"Invalid token passed"}'`

I want to see what `token` is being sent as part of the http call. How could this be done.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `http://httpbin.org/get`? You can see the access token using it. The sample script and result are as follows.

#### Sample script :

```
import requests
import datetime
date_11_days_back = (datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=11)).isoformat()
date_now = datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()
webinars_url = "http://httpbin.org/get"
params = {
    'fromTime': date_11_days_back,
    'toTime': date_now
}
headers = {
    'Authorization': "TOK:{}".format("### access token ###")
}

last_week_webinars = requests.get(webinars_url, headers=headers, params=params)
print(last_week_webinars.text)
```

#### Result :

```
{
  "args": {
    "fromTime": "2017-01-01T00:00:00.000000",
    "toTime": "2017-01-02T00:00:00.000000"
  },
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
    "Authorization": "TOK:### access token ###",
    "Connection": "close",
    "Host": "httpbin.org",
    "User-Agent": "python-requests"
  },
  "origin": "#####",
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/get?toTime=2017-01-02T00%3a00%3a00%2e000000&fromTime=2017-01-01T00%3a00%3a00%2e000000"
}
```

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

What I wanted to see was what TOKEN is being passed as part of the headers, passed as part of the HTTP request fired by requests.

Here is how you may take a look at it.

`response.request.headers` : This shows you all the headers passed with their corresponding values.

Additionally, to find out the response(which is last_week_webinars in question) headers, `response.headers` gives the answer.

Also the problem with my request was the way `fromTime` and `toTime` are passed.